# how can I replace input text field into text in span?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to replace text field into non-editable field after typing value in text field.

```
<input type="text" id="text" value="">
<input type="button" id="btn" value="click">
```

After I input data value in text field and click button, i want to replace these text field and button into text in span.

```
<span id="changedText"></span>
```

How can I do that with Jquery? 
  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should get value in input element at first:

```
var data = $("#text").val();
```

And then create span element and replace input with it

```
$("#text").replaceWith('<span id="changedText">'+data+'</span>')
```

All this will happen when user clicks button

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
     var data = $("#text").val();
     $("#text").replaceWith('<span id="changedText">'+data+'</span>') 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this -

```
$('#btn').on('click',function(){
   $('#text').replaceWith("<span id='changedText'>"+$('#text').val()+"</span>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

initially, hide the span.On button click hide the input, copy the text to span, and show the span.

[click here to see it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/UeZAS/)

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
   $("#changedText").html($("#text").val());
   $("#text").hide();
});
```